# About the astar algorithm in boost graph library

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, a-star

I found this A star algorithm implementation of boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html particularly the example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/example/astar-cities.cpp.

When I used that example on my graph, I found that the edges are not directed. I mean in certain cases my edges are directed, however, it seems that it ignores it. How, can I modify to make it directed

Comment: ok I figured it out. I just had to set the graph to directed